Oracle Apex invoking external REST api
I've installed Apex 23.2 on Oracle DB 19c and ORDS. Both ORDS and DB are running on two different servers.
When attempting to set up REST Data Sources for calling an external API from the Apex developer page, I encounter this error:
"An error occurred during URL invocation.
ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)"
the DB server is isolated which will not allow to access external URLs or the internet. In this situation how to access external API in Oracle APEX ?

Error starts with "ORA".... so 100% sure database related. ORDS Server is no database (just java code) and your rest call is invoked from within pl/sql, so it's the DB Server. Issue is that the database does not allow calling the external API because no ACL exists that allows it.

You need to add an ACL for the database ... however, if "the DB server is isolated which will not allow to access external URLs or the internet." then you have a problem as the database is the one trying to access the internet and if it is forbidden from doing so by the firewall (or something else) then what you are doing sounds like it is never going to work (even if you add an ACL) and you need a different solution.
